# How do I get GroupBy count from an eloquent collection?

Tags: php, collections, laravel

I have been looking around a lot to achieve this, but couldn't find a solution yet.

I have to get session details and counts. I am using the following code, but stuck on how to get the count after grouping the collection on date.

Here is the code:

```
$sessions = Session::where('api_token','1')
             ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
         ->get(array(DB::raw('date(created_at) as v_date')));

//To get the total session counts -
$total_sessions = $sessions->count();

//To get the sessions that happened today -
$today_sessions = $sessions->filter(function($today)
{ if ($today->v_date == date("Y-m-d")) { return true; }})->count();
```

Now I get the collection grouped using groupBy()

```
$sessions->groupBy('v_date'));
```

But how do I retrieve the session count and date from this collection.

Expected output:

2014-02-01     10
2014-02-02     11
2014-02-04     15
2014-02-06     70
2014-02-07      90
2014-02-08    100

Comment: I'm confused by your question, really didn't get it, did you mean `$sessions->groupBy('v_date'))->count();` ?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha - I have table Session. I retrieve all data for an api_token in my collection $sessions. Now I need three values from this.
1- Total Sessions count.
2- Count of Sessions That happened today.
3- Date wise count of sessions.

Now as in the question, I am able to get 1 & 2. How do I get the datewise count from the collection ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get a count of sessions per day then there is no need to use Eloquent you can just use query builder.

```
$sessions = DB::table('sessions')
            ->select(DB::raw('date(created_at) AS v_date, count(*) AS count'))
            ->where('api_token', '1')
            ->orderBy('v_date', 'desc')
            ->groupBy('v_date')
            ->get();
```

This will return an array of objects representing each row:

```
array (size=1)
    0 => 
      object(stdClass)[346]
        public 'v_date' => string '2014-03-09' (length=10)
        public 'count' => int 2
    1 =>
      object(stdClass)[349]
        public 'v_date' => string '2014-03-08' (length=10)
        public 'count' => int 6
```

Comment: Thanks @RMcLeod Three things I want to get from the collection.
1- Total Sessions count.     2- Count of Sessions That happened today.   3- Date wise count of sessions.